# I have a confusion about the pre and post increment in c programming

Tags: c

according to the precedence table pre increment should be execute 1'st then the post increment execute so how to following code will generate answer 11 shoudn't be it generate 10?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a=2;
    int b=++ a + a++ +4;
    printf("%d",b);

    return 0;
}
```

Heres how i think:

1. a++: increase the value of 'a' from 2 to 3 but as it's an post increment it takes the previous   value which is 2.
2. ++a:increase the value of 'a' from 3 to 4.

so the result should be: 4+2+4 = 10

so the altimate result should be: 4+2+4 = 10

Comment: The code has undefined behavior.

Comment: You modify `a` twice in the same expression without any sequencing, that leads to *undefined behavior*. See the duplicate for more details.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/bcdsf9hK4 <- 10 and 11 are definitely possible. Code has undefined behavior, do not spend any more braincells on it, do not write code like this.